# Visual Studio: Auto correct specific spelling mistake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, spell-checking, autocorrect

Often when coding in javascript i type

```
funciton
```

instead of

```
function
```

I would like to autocorrect this spelling mistake whenever this particular error occurs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Spell Checker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce) and [HTML Spell Checker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0db4814c-255e-4cc6-a2c2-a428de7f8949) extensions from the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/).

Comment: do these tools have the ability to auto correct specific errors?

Comment: Not auto correct, but it will mark misspelled words on the fly.

Comment: yeah that won't cut it as I can see it is already incorrect as it is underlined already.

Comment: Well I'm not aware of any _auto correct_ tool, maybe there's a commercial one out there

Answer (score 0):

Well when you make a spelling mistake or some other kind of syntactical mistake visual studio shows a red cursive line under that statement just like the one shown in the  **Microsoft Word** when you have. Many times the red line is a little ahead of the mistake but the mistake is definitely in the code before the red line.